# Implicit conversion on Null type

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to reproduce a C# syntax in Scala:

The C# code:

```
val myValue = myObject ?? new MyClass();
```

basically 'myValue' will contains 'myObject' if it's not null, or a new instance of 'MyClass' if it's null.

This is the Scala code which I tried to run:

```
case class ShortCond(original: Any){
  def ??(fallback : Any) {
    if (original == null)
      return fallback
    return original
  }
}
implicit def any2ShortCond(original: Any) = ShortCond(original)


val myString = null
val value = myString ?? "myString is null"
```

It works when myString is not null, but fails when myString is null, it returns:

```
error: value ?? is not a member of Null
val value = myString ?? "myString is null"
```

I understand the error, but is there a way to achieve this in Scala or it is not possible?

Thanks

Comment: Scala encourages you to not use `null` in your code at all. That's what you should strive to do.

Comment: I know this is a bad practice to use null in Scala code, but the null value can be returned through a library method call and you have to deal with it.

Comment: You're right. The actual thing to do is usually take care of the `null` values from 3rd party libraries at the lowest level you can, and then propagate `Option[T]` or other null avoiding values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1st suggestion: you should try to stick to Scala idioms when writing Scala code. The Scala way to do this might be something like ...

```
implicit class ShortCond(original: Any){
  def ??(fallback : Any) =
    Option(original).getOrElse(fallback)
}

val str:String = null
str ?? 34  // res0: Any = 34
"x" ?? 43  // res1: Any = x
```

But this is a bad idea for a number of reasons, mainly you're trying to return mixed types, which means that the compiler resolves it to type `Any`, which is not good Scala.  Once the compiler doesn't know what type your `val` is then you're removing yourself from the full support of the type system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The C# syntax that I appreciate to use involves some Scala bad practices...

Comment: If you parameterize the implicit class with a generic type it will prevent the use of `Any` and type mixing.

Comment: @puhlen, if we have `class ShortCond[A]` and `def ??[B]` then the return type is still going to be the lowest upper bound (LUB) for A and B, which is likely to be `Any`. The real solution is to return `Either[A,B]` but that's not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of something like `class ShortCond[A]` and `def ??(fallback: A):A`  The fallback must be the same type as the original.

Comment: @puhlen, yes, that would indeed to a long way toward cleaning this up but it's not at all clear the it would satisfy the OP's first example: `myObject ?? new MyClass()` If `myObject` is restricted to a null-able instance of `myClass` then I completely agree with your suggestion.